# Remove environmental variable programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, environment-variables

I need to write a unit test for some C++ code that checks for the presence of an environmental variable. I'm using MSVS 2008 and gtest as my framework. I add the environmental variable using putenv, I check the environmental variable using getevn, but I can't figure out how to remove it so that no other test will see it. I realize this is probably easy, but I can't find the answer on the internet. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `putenv` again specifying `"SOME_VAR="` as parameter will delete environment variable `SOME_VAR`. btw, Microsoft recommends using `_putenv` as `putenv` is deprecated.

Comment: Note that at least on Solaris there's no mention of this feature in the man page.

Comment: He is using MSVS 2008. Implies he is working on Windows. On Linux, I would use setenv and unsetenv. Don't know if Solaris has those though.

Answer (score 2):

You could always fork/exec a subprocess to do just the `putenv`/`getenv` testing, and then when it terminates there isn't any stray environment left around.

Comment: I thought of that, but was shooting for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the env var to an empty string?

From cmd.exe, this works:

```
set SOMEVAR=something
echo %SOMEVAR%
set SOMEVAR=
echo %SOMEVAR%
```

Where the last one shows it has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `unsetenv` function.

If vc2008 lacks this function, you can directly access the environment using [`getenv_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb2sfw2z(VS.80).aspx), and remove the entry manually, simulating `unsetenv`.

Comment: Is that actually available on Windows without using the POSIX subsystem? Google is turning up inconsistent results...