# Boost locale - unset LANG needed when creating temporary files

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, locale

I am building a C++ project using CMake and have recently added temporary file creation using the Boost C++ library. This is how I have included Boost in the CMake files:

```
# get boost
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${exe_name} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
ADD_LIBRARY(${lib_name} ${common_SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${lib_name} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${exe_name} ${lib_name})
```

This is how I call it in C++:

```cpp
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
...
input_file *Utils::get_input_file_from_string(const std::string &inp) {
    std::string real_inp(inp);

    boost::filesystem::path temp_path = boost::filesystem::unique_path();
    const std::string temp_pathstr = temp_path.native();
        
    boost::filesystem::path temp_folder = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path();
    const std::string temp_folderstr = temp_folder.native();
    const std::string temp_fname = temp_folderstr + "/" + temp_pathstr;
    
    const char *temp_pathchar = temp_fname.c_str();

    ...

    FILE *temp = fopen(temp_pathchar, "wb+");
    ...
    input_file *ret = new input_file;
    loadInput(ret, temp);

    fclose(temp);

    return ret;
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, by running the bash command...

```sh
unset LANG
```

...the program runs successfully (note that `echo $LANG` returns `C.UTF-8`)

Is there a way to edit the program so that I do not need to run the `unset LANG` command every time I load a new shell instance?

EDIT: I am aware that it is possible to unset an environment variable within c++ but I believe that there must be a solution within Boost related to the locale that ensures the error is not raised.

(PS Just to reiterate, the program runs successfully with the desired output when `unset LANG` is called before running the executable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove environmental variable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205197/remove-environmental-variable-programmatically) Unsetting the environment variable at the start of your program may fix the issue.

Comment: It is helpful as a workaround but I am looking for some code specific to boost that ensures that this error is not raised - my thoughts are that I am missing an import or a command in the cmake file that ensures the locale is set correctly within boost

Comment: You should probably set the required locale - or if it needs to be system dependent, pass the correct one to use (as a command line argument?). In the latter case you could argue that it's also fine to set `LANG` to the required value.

Comment: I believe it would be helpful if you included the current value of LANG. And I feel your pain - bad use of i18n environment variables has unfortunately been common for quite some time but at least some C++ libraries allow you to explicitly specify a locale in the calls; regardless of the environment.

Comment: @HansOlsson the current `LANG` is `C.UTF-8` - question edited to note this

Comment: MacOS or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug this well without back-and-forth or access to your machine as I couldn't reproduce this locally. I'll take a crack at it anyway. My guess is the locale issues come up due to the `.native()` conversion to a `std::string`. Try this instead:

```cpp
input_file *Utils::get_input_file_from_string(const std::string &inp) {
    ...
    boost::filesystem::path temp_path = boost::filesystem::unique_path();
    boost::filesystem::path temp_folder = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path();
    boost::filesystem::path temp_file_path = temp_folder / temp_path;

    // try either:
    std::string temp_file_path_string = temp_file_path.string();    
    const char *temp_pathchar = temp_file_path_string.c_str();
    // or:
    const char *temp_pathchar = temp_file_path.c_str();
    ...
}
```

This will not behave well on non-POSIX platforms if you go with the lines that use `string()` due to the use of forward slashes.

Also, I'd try to do some more minimization of the code shown. It seems possible that `unique_path()` is throwing the error. Try hardcoding a path or path string and see if the error persists, for example.